# powershell convert the date property to string when using ConvertTo-Json

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'd like to get all Hyper-V VM information from [`Get-VM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vm?view=win10-ps) cmdlet as below:

`Get-Vm | Select-Object * | ConvertTo-Json`

Where the `CreationTime` in each VM dictionary looks like `\/Date(-11644473600000)\/",` in the output

How can I make it look like this format `2017/11/29 16:09:00` in the output json?

When I guess it is the number of Epoch timestamp, I found it sometimes a negative number.

I found some articles taking about this issue which take [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1) for example, but in my case it is a property in `Get-VM` that I am not sure if a faster way to convert the date property without long script to parse the output.

Comment: How about `get-vm | select *, @{Name="ReadableCreationTime"; Expression={Get-Date $_.CreationTime}} -ExcludeProperty CreationTime | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select a Property based on an user defined Expression one can define them in [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) the following way:

```
Get-VM | Select-Object -Property @{Name="ReadableCreationTime"; Expression={Get-Date $_.CreationTime}}, *
```

This selects the user defined property `ReadableCreationTime` and all other properties (`*`).

Now, you want to exclude the original `CreationTime` as it is a) hard to read and b) redundant to `ReadableCreationTime`. This can be done using the [`-ExcludeProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1#optional-parameters) parameter:

```
Get-VM | Select-Object -Property @{Name="ReadableCreationTime"; Expression={Get-Date $_.CreationTime}}, * -ExcludeProperty CreationTime
```

...And pipe the result to `ConvertTo-Json`

Keep in mind that while reading  the resulting json, you have to parse the date, because it is just a string, not a valid Date value.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't meant to down vote, but it happened.Your answer helped me .Thanks and i again apolozise